# MS Chart not displayed in custom Web Part

Tags: web-part, wss-3.0, wss, chart

I am using WSS 3.0 and am trying to display a Chart object from the System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting namespace in a custom Web Part. My Web Part was built in C# in Visual Studio 2008, and I am using WSP Builder to deploy. My ultimate goal is to show items from a List in the chart, but at the moment I am just making a simple chart with one series. My code works on an ASP.NET WebForm, but when I copy and paste the code to a custom Web Part, all I see is a rectangle with the red X.

Here is my code, though I think the problem is elsewhere:

```
Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
Chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");
Chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
for (int 1 = 0; i <= 50; i++)
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(i, i*2);
this.Controls.Add(Chart1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below tag under  section of web.config of the web application where you are using it and create a folder "C:\TempImageFiles"

```
<add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
```

Comment: I have done that, it still does not render.

Comment: @CigarDoug - Try following this:
 http://asifhuddani.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/chart-control-asp-net-4-0-and-iis-7-problem/